# Open links in textview

Tags: xcode, url, swift, random, textview

I am coding on a project were the user presses a button and a in the textview(named textoutput) under the button the program randomly takes a link from a array i have named textinfo. When running the project the first time you press the the button and presses the link the right link opens up in safari but the second time the button is pressed and a new randomly selected link is shown and when pressing the link it opens the first link and not the one pressed. This continues every time when pressing the button that just the first link is open when pressing a new link.

```
@IBAction func Frukostaction(sender: UIButton) {


    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(19))

    textoutput.text = textinfo[random]

}
```

How do a fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting the `UITextView.delegate` and then calling openURL manually inside `shouldInteractWithURL` function. For example.

```
let links = ["http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com","http://www.discovery.com"]
var textView : UITextView!
var currentLinkIndex : Int = 0


@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    let random : Int = Int(arc4random()) % 3

    textView.text = links[random]
    currentLinkIndex = random
}

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

    let url = NSURL(string:links[currentLinkIndex])
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
    return false
}
```

Comment: I get it to work so that the button shows the array with links. But i have problems with defining which textView that the ...shouldInteract... commando should use. Or what to say. I am pretty new to swift hehe. But when you say "setting the UITextView.delegate" do you mean "var textView : UITextView!" or should i define it earlier somehow? @rakeshbs

Comment: read this to understand what a delegate is. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uitextview-uitextviewdelegate--mobile-11210

Comment: I have read the tutorial several times and tried to implement the    "textview.delegate = self" in my code and just gets the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and in the text bar at the left it shows that all of my "UiTextView:s" (i have nine of them) have the value of nil. I think i understands the concept of delegate, but cant get it to work, so do/is it easier som how to manually set the values of the textview somehow?  Thanks for the answers.  @rakeshbs